# Dynamically changing image inside an SVG from API

Tags: reactjs, svg

Currently I have an SVG component that is taking a xlinkHref to fill an image inside the SVG. I am manually putting an image inside, but I want it to be placed via the API call that I am making. Currently this is my code:

```
function SvgComponent(props) {
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="3em"
      viewBox="0 0 850 1090"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
      height="3em"
      {...props}
    >
      <clipPath id="clip">
        <path
          id="path"
          transform="translate(0,1090) scale(1,-1)"
          d="M406 1035 c-32 -49 -201 -104 -323 -105 l-43 0 0 -282 c0 -277 1     -284 24 -333 39 -82 146 -174 291 -250 l67 -34 61 31 c151 76 265 170 303 253     23 49 24 57 24 330 l0 281 -103 12 c-124 13 -206 42 -252 87 l-33 34 -16 -24z"
        />
      </clipPath>
      <image
        x={-200}
        y={30}
        width={1090}
        height={1090}
        clipPath="url(#clip)"
        xlinkHref="https://assets.codepen.io/222579/darwin300.jpg"
      />
      <use xlinkHref="#path" fill="none" stroke="gold" strokeWidth={30} />
    </svg>
  );
}

export default function Map({ posts }) {
  return (
    <>
            {posts &&
              posts.map((maps) => (
                      <SvgComponent/>
             ))}
    </> )}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/maps");
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { posts },
  };
}
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/full-popup-mapbox-stackoverflow-forked-xf1ei?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @RobertLongson can you please make the changes in the Sandbox and show me

Comment: I've kept it at a minimum here https://codesandbox.io/s/full-popup-mapbox-stackoverflow-forked-xf1ei?file=/src/App.js

Comment: And where is the API call?...

Comment: @RobertLongson I am fetching my data from my strapi API, but for the codeSandbox I've placed dummy data because it works in the same way

Comment: Although the question is lacking some information, I think you are looking for a plain prop. E.g. `xlinkHref={props.image}` and `<SvgComponent image={maps.img} />`.

Comment: @Chris Yes that solved the problem. Thanks